# Actions to do in a Pull Request with 'requested changes' to notify that changes have been done

Tags: github, pull-request

I have created a pull request in GitHub that has been reviewed and the reviewer has requested changes. I have done the changes and added a comment in the pull request conversation with a reference to the reviewer so I expect a notification has been sent to him.

Is there any other thing I must do in GitHub to reflect that I have pushed corrections to the requested changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you did is standard operating procedure when replying to a change request in a pull request.  Since you pushed your changes, the branch in question has been updated.  If your reviewer's GitHub is configured to not receive notifications he may not have received one, but from your point of view you have met your expectations.  The other Git repositories (e.g. Bitbucket) also behave similarly to this.

Comment: Thanks Biegeleisen, so the only think I can do is to make sure that the reviewer is aware of my changes.

Comment: Yes, and this can be a problem because sometimes people ignore the change and comment notifications.  Ideally, the ball is your reviewer's court now, but if you have a deadline for that feature you may have to prod some people into completing the pull request.